# Why would a graph query work from one machine but not another?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Our application is using the following URL to access excel files in a directory on our sharepoint

https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/sites/procurusgroup.sharepoint.com/drives/b!1EAhhLt1d0ilvwyzEK16TK9_Q6DZAx5FitIdvr4xA4Nu-QCiS4MTRI6miw9Woz6f/root:/Felixstowe%20Warehouse/Daily%20Work%20Schedule:/children

This has been working absolutely fine however last night it started failing on the application server.

I logged in to Graph explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to try and diagnose the problem and the URL worked fine from my local machine.  I logged on to the Graph explorer on the application server and received the following error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Open navigation properties are not supported on OpenTypes. Property name: 'getByPath'.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "6039691c-9f4f-4cdb-a5fd-dfb266174385",
        "date": "2019-03-05T16:10:10"
        }
    }
}
```

How can accessing a REST GET URL be non-deterministic based on the location it is called from?  Does that not break REST rules?

Any help would be much appreciated.  Also does anyone know how to raise a support ticket for the Graph API?

Thanks

Comment: Very strangely the problem has now cleared itself with no changes made.

Comment: If you have access to your [O365 Service Health Dashboard in the admin portal](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/servicehealth), look for SP175272.